# PHP while-loop not working with mysql_result

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a Physician Query:

```
// Primary Physician Query
$qPhysician = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM physicians ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC");
$rowPhysician = mysql_fetch_array($qPhysician);

// State Query for Physician
$idStatePhysician = $rowPhysician['idstate'];
$qStatePhysician = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE idstate=$idStatePhysician");
$rowStatePhysician = mysql_fetch_array($qStatePhysician);

// City Query for Physician
$idCityPhysician = $rowPhysician['idcity'];
$qCityPhysician = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE idcities=$idCityPhysician");
$rowCityPhysician = mysql_fetch_array($qCityPhysician);
```

I have a while loop to display all physicians row to a table:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($qPhysician);
    $i=0;
    while($i < $num)
        {
        $idphysicians = $rowPhysician['idphysicians'];
        if ($i % 2 == 0){
        echo "<tr class='even' onclick=\"DoNav('physicianUpdate.php?idphysicians=$idphysicians');\">";
        }
        else{
        echo "<tr class='odd' onclick=\"DoNav('physicianUpdate.php?idphysicians=$idphysicians');\">";
        }
        echo "<td>" . mysql_result($qPhysician,$i,"lastName") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . mysql_result($qPhysician,$i,"firstName") . "</td>";
        echo "<td>"; 
        if(isset($rowPhysician['idcity'])){echo mysql_result($qCityPhysician,$i,"name");} else{}
        echo "</td>";
        $i++;
        }
```

My problem is: I have 3 rows of data from my physicians table. Each has a value for 'idcity' reflecting the idnumber from my City table. However, the 1st row of Data displays the idcity=Name properly, but the 2nd and 3rd row gave an error:

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 1 on MySQL result index 7 in C:\wamp\www\iPOC\physicians.php on line 55
```

Also, if I have a blank value for idcity on one of the row, it also generates an error.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `mysql_result()` with a one-way result. The correct fix is to use one of the `mysql_fetch_*()` functions instead, checking the returned value in your while loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qPhysician)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: when I changed it to this code, it shows like a hundreds of records of the same thing and it wasn't stopping. So I manually killed the task for loading

Comment: ok it kinda work, but it only displayed the last 2 rows. The row "Arnold Villaluz" did not display.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would probably work better:

```
$qCityPhysician = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE idcities=$idCityPhysician");
$qCityPhysicians = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qCityPhysician)) {
   $qCityPhysicians[$row['idcity']] = $row['name'];
}
$qPhysician = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM physicians ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC");
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qPhysician)) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>"; 
        if(isset($row['idcity'])) {
            echo $qCityPhysicians[$row['idcity']];
        }
        echo "</td>";
        $i++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you really want "if ($i % 2 == 0) {" in there? That would cause it to skip every odd row.

Comment: the reason why I have that. It's for my alternating row: if ($i % 2 == 0){
   echo "<tr class='even' onclick=\"DoNav('physicianUpdate.php?idphysicians=$idphysicians');\">";
   }
   else{
   echo "<tr

Comment: ok, I re-updated the code with the actual one. I was trying to show less code as possible to avoid confusion :)

Comment: ok, i got all the errors out by putting if isset before running the query for each city table and state table. But my problem now is, I have 3 rows of data, but only 2 gets displayed. The last row is not showing up.